# Memory leak when using QThread and QPrinter

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qt5, qprinter

I'm using `QThread` for printing work via `QPrinter`

My `PrintWorker` look like this :

```
class PrintWorker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PrintWorker(QThread*, QPrinter*, QPicture*, QPainter*, QObject *parent = 0);

private:
    QPicture *_picture = nullptr;
    QPrinter *_printer = nullptr;
    QPainter *_painter = nullptr;

    public slots:
    void print();

signals:
    void done();
};

PrintWorker::PrintWorker(QThread *thread, QPrinter *printer, QPicture *picture, QPainter *painter, QObject *parent) :QObject(parent),
_picture(picture), _printer(printer), _painter(painter)
{
    moveToThread(thread);
    QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::started, this, &PrintWorker::print);
    QObject::connect(this, &PrintWorker::done, thread, &QThread::quit);
    QObject::connect(this, &PrintWorker::done, this, &PrintWorker::deleteLater);
    QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::finished, thread, &QThread::deleteLater);
}

void PrintWorker::print() {
    // do some print job with painter and picture
    emit done();
}
```

And `print` Method is this :

```
void NewService::print() {
    if (!_printer) { /* _printer : a private member */
        _printer = new QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution);
        _printer->setPageSize(QPrinter::A5);
        _printer->setPageOrientation(QPageLayout::Portrait);
        _printer->setColorMode(QPrinter::Color);
    }

    if (!_printDialog) { /* _printDialog : a private member */
        _printDialog = new QPrintDialog(_printer);
    }

    if (_printDialog->exec() == QPrintDialog::Accepted) {
        MyWidget *widget = new MyWidget(/* some args*/);

        QPainter *painter = new QPainter;
        QPicture *picture = new QPicture;
        widget->render(picture);

        QThread *thread = new QThread;
        PrintWorker *worker = new PrintWorker(thread, _printer, picture, painter);
        thread->start();
    }
}
```

Now before invoking `print()` my app exposes about 9MB of memory after printing and invoking `PrintWorker::print()` my app's memory usage get to 26MB

In Another world if we remove `emit done` at last part in `PrintWorker::print()` it makes no difference.

What we expect after finishing job is memory usage should get down to 26MB - Thread space + `_printer` + `_printDialog` objects size ≈ 14MB

So What's wrong with this ?

Comment: have you tried to add a qDebug see if the destructor of your print worker is getting called?

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez.Yes `PrintWorker::~PrintWorker()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting `PrintWorker` and `QThread` objects, but not `QPainter`, `QPicture`, `MyWidget`, `QPrintDialog` nor `QPrinter`. Those are memory leaks (`new` with no `delete`). Note that `PrintWorker` destructor could take care of deleting `QPainter`, `QPicture` and `QPrinter`, additionnaly, it could also take ownership of `MyWidget` and delete it. Hopefully `QPrintDialog` object is deleted by `NewService` class, but it's hard to say as code was not posted.

Also, as recommende by rafael gonzalez, you should check that `QThread` `PrintWorker` and `QThread` are actually being deleted.

By the way, how did you check memory usage? Through a leak detection tool (like valgrind, VLD...)? Or through Windows Task Manager. Because task manager is definitely unaccurate.

Comment: Yes the measurement tool is Windows task manger and also Yes PrintWorker::~PrintWorker() is called and i don't get it i make my thread object private and set `QObject::connect(_printThread, &QThread::destroyed, this, &NewService::onPrintDone);` now i'm seeing `QObject(0x2647bb040f0)` via `qDebug() << _printThread;` !! so it doesn't get deleted

Comment: Deleting `_printThread` won't change the pointer address, it may still show `QObject(0x2647bb040f0)` even if deleted. Also, onPrintDone may be called before `QThread` is actually deleted by `deleteLater` mechanism. Finally, task manager show you memory usage of your app, which does not necessarily shrink when you delet an object. You must use a leak detector tool.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `QThread::quit()` you are activly exiting the EventLoop in this thread. A `QObject::deleteLater()` for objects residing in this thread may not be executed anymore (though they mention on `QThread::finished()`-signal the delete later slot will still be called).

I personally would just set up the connection using the `finished()` signal or set the parent of the worker-object to be the thread itself, then Qt actually has to remove the object.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#exit